# how can i build luasocket on msys2

Tags: msys2, luasocket

Am new to lua/luajit. I was looking for a socket api for lua, and luasocket came up in searches, pacman -Ss luasocket doesnt exist so I have to compile it from source. Have not been successful, I was wondering if anyone can provide a makefile to build luasocket on msys2? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I made a fork to to this using mingw64 and lua 5.3.
It's not as clean I wish it could be but it works : https://github.com/pmalhaire/luasocket

build and install :

```
$  git clone git@github.com:pmalhaire/luasocket.git
[...]
$  cd luasocket
[...]
$  make LUAV=5.3 PLAT=msys2
[...]
$  make LUAV=5.3 PLAT=msys2 install
[...]
$  make test
lua test/hello.lua
Hello from LuaSocket 3.0-rc1 and MIME 1.0.3!
```

Comment: Thank you @Pierrot